# Fullcalendar Custom View stops me looking at past dates

Tags: jquery, date, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullcalendar

Hi the remit I've got is a simple one. Amend a calendar that I've already got to view the 'agenda' view 2 weeks in the past and the next/prev should just move one day forward/back.

Seems simple, checked the documentation - new features seem to have been added.
I upgraded my calendar to 3.9 using nuget and plugged in a custom view.
But whatever I try can't go back. Tried 3.3.1 same.

What am I doing wrong - or am I? Is this a fullcalendar bug?

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaTwoWeeks,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek,listDay'
         },
         weekends: false,
         minTime: '08:00:00',
         maxTime : '17:00:00',
         buttonText: {
             listWeek: 'Weekly',
             listDay: 'Daily',
         },

         views: {

             agendaTwoWeeks: {
                 type: 'agenda',

                 dayCount: 14
                 /*visibleRange: function(currentDate) {

                     console.log("current date "+currentDate.format());

                     var ret =  {
                         start: currentDate.clone().subtract(1, 'days'),
                         end: currentDate.clone().add(3, 'days') // exclusive end, so 3
                     };
                     console.log(ret.start.format());
                     console.log(ret.end.format());


                     return ret;
                 }*/


             },

             agendaWeek: { // name of view
                 titleFormat: 'D MMM YYYY',
                 columnFormat: 'ddd D/M'
                 // other view-specific options here
             },
             agendaDay: { // name of view
                 titleFormat: 'D MMM YYYY',
                 columnFormat: 'dddd'
                 // other view-specific options here
             },
             listWeek: { // name of view
                 titleFormat: 'D MMM YYYY',
                 columnFormat: 'ddd D/M'
                 // other view-specific options here
             },
             listDay: { // name of view
                 titleFormat: 'D MMM YYYY',
                 columnFormat: 'ddd D/M'
                 // other view-specific options here
             },

         },

        defaultDate: '2018-09-21',
        /*validRange: {
            start:'2017-09-18',
            end: '2019-09-18'
        },*/
        firstDay : 1,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        editable: true,
        eventDurationEditable: false,
        allDaySlot: false,
        eventTextColor: '#000000',
        slotDuration: '00:15:00',
        slotLabelInterval : '00:15:00',

    });

});
```

The view is `agendaTwoWeeks` I've played with daycount,duration, visibleRange , validRange - nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, it's the `weekends = false` that's causing the issue.
I'll have a look at the visibleRange and how to get around it.

R

Update, had a look and it's a no. It can't seem to grasp the current date not being a weekend and even though you can get the skip one way it doesn't work the other. 
Ideally there would be a function to state what the next day would be on click.